# How to detect if an image is in another image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I am trying to detect if an image is a 100 % match to being in another image, and then set a variable to `True` if it is. But all the things I have read have turned up little to no results apart from one particular thread in which this code is given.

```
import cv2

method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

# Read the images from the file
small_image = cv2.imread('ran_away.png')
large_image = cv2.imread('pokemon_card.png')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)

# We want the minimum squared difference
mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

# Draw the rectangle:
# Extract the coordinates of our best match
MPx,MPy = mnLoc

# Step 2: Get the size of the template. This is the same size as the match.
trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]

# Step 3: Draw the rectangle on large_image
cv2.rectangle(large_image, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),2)

# Display the original image with the rectangle around the match.
cv2.imshow('output',large_image)

# The image is only displayed if we call this
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However this opens up an output, and does stuff I do not want to do. All I want to do is to detect, if an image is in an image, and if it is, then print that to the console. In my particular circumstances, I am trying to detect if this image

[image: Ran_away.png]

is in this image

[image: Pokemon_card.png]

and if it is, print to the console that the pokemon has ran away.

Answer (score 4):

Your code shows basic template matching. Please work through some [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) on that topic, and the documentation on [`cv2.matchTemplate`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be), especially to understand the different [template match modes](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d).

I can only think of the following solution to approach your task: Instead of using `TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`, use `TM_SQDIFF`, such that you get absolute values in the `result` instead of relative values:

- For `TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`, the best match will always be some value near `0.0`, even if the match isn't correct.
- For `TM_SQDIFF`, some value near `0.0` indicates an actual correct
  match.

So, now, simply write a method, that does the template matching, and detects, if the minimum value of `result` is below some threshold near `0.0`, let's say `10e-6`. If so, print out whatever you want, if not, do something else:

```py
import cv2


def is_template_in_image(img, templ):

    # Template matching using TM_SQDIFF: Perfect match => minimum value around 0.0
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, templ, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

    # Get value of best match, i.e. the minimum value
    min_val = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)[0]

    # Set up threshold for a "sufficient" match
    thr = 10e-6

    return min_val <= thr


# Read template
template = cv2.imread('ran_away.png')

# Collect image file names
images = ['pokemon_card.png', 'some_other_image.png']

for image in images:
    if is_template_in_image(cv2.imread(image), template):
        print('{}: {}'.format(image, 'Pokemon has ran away.'))
    else:
        print('{}: {}'.format(image, 'Nothing to see here.'))
```

The output:

```
pokemon_card.png: Pokemon has ran away.
some_other_image.png: Nothing to see here.
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using the relatively new NumPy method [sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view).

> Create a sliding window view into the array with the given window shape.
>
> Also known as rolling or moving window, the window slides across all dimensions of
> the array and extracts subsets of the array at all window positions.
>
> New in version 1.20.0.

*Note: I have installed the latest NumPy version in a new virtual environment due to compatibility issues concerns.*

Simple test for checking how sliding_window_view works:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

t = np.array([[ [0,0,0], [1,1,1]],
              [ [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]])

x = np.array([[ [0,0,0],  [1,1,1],  [2,2,2],  [3,3,3]],
              [[10,10,10], [11,11,11], [12,12,12], [13,13,13]],
              [[20,20,20], [21,21,21], [22,22,22], [23,23,23]]])

x[1:3, 1:3, :] = t  # Copy t to x - it looks like there is a problem along edges

v = sliding_window_view(x, (2,2,3))

print(v-t)
```

Result starts with:

```
[[[[[[ 0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0]]
```

That means that `t` is subtracted from all "windows" of `v` as expected.

---

Add the following command for testing [np.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
print(np.where((v == t).all(axis=(3, 4, 5))))
```

The output is:

```
(array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

`all(axis=(3, 4, 5))` is `True` if all elements along axis 3, 4 and 5 are `True`.
In the above example we found a match in index [1, 1].

---

Here is a solution for detecting a perfect match (using NumPy):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

# Read the images from the file
small_image = cv2.imread('ran_away.png')
#small_image = cv2.imread('icon.png');
large_image = cv2.imread('pokemon_card.png')

v = sliding_window_view(large_image, small_image.shape)

match_idx = np.where((v == small_image).all(axis=(3, 4, 5)))

if len(match_idx[0]) > 0:
    row = match_idx[0][0]
    col = match_idx[1][0]

    cv2.rectangle(large_image, (col, row), (col+small_image.shape[1], row+small_image.shape[1]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('large_image', large_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]